# Filter a multi dimensional JS array using a keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array that looks like this:

```
[['place', '1', '-2'],['place2', '1', '-2'],['place3', '1', '-3']]
```

I want to filter it using a keyword from onClick so it looks like this:

```
[['place', '1', '-2'],['place2', '1', '-2']]
```

If my filter is for example -2.

The code i'm using now is (where object is the variable being filtered):

```
return $.map(object, function (item, key) {
   if (item[0] === value) {
       return item;
   }
});
```

And then I call it using:

```
var markers = results(filter);
```

But the result I get is blank.

Hopefully I am making sense if not I am very sorry please let me know and I can try to clarify.

Comment: do you like to search in every element for `-2`?

Comment: If your value to be filtered  appears anywhere in array you can also use index of on inner array in addition to answers given. But it might not work on older browsers.

Comment: @NinaScholz in this example yes

Comment: @ShaileshVaishampayan my goal is to have a filter for [1] [0] [2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for it and return the filtered items.

```js
var data = [['place', '1', '-2'], ['place2', '1', '-2'], ['place3', '1', '-3']],
    filtered = data.filter(function (a) {
        return a[2] === '-2';
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

Search for any item with the given string

```js
var data = [['place', '1', '-2'], ['place2', '1', '-2'], ['place3', '1', '-3']],
    filtered = data.filter(function (a) {
        return a.some(function (b) {
            return b === '-2';
        });
    });

console.log(filtered);
```

ES6, Search for any item with the given string

```js
var data = [['place', '1', '-2'], ['place2', '1', '-2'], ['place3', '1', '-3']],
    filtered = data.filter(a => a.some(b => b === '-2'));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: This could work I will give it a try thanks

Comment: This almost works. One issue I am having is return a[3] === 'text'; works while return a[3] === filterfromfunction; does not any idea?

Comment: please add the content of `filterfromfunction`.

Comment: I ended up making a global variable and that worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    var places = [['place', '1', '-2'],['place2', '1', '-2'],['place3', '1', '-3']]
    var result = places.filter(place => place[2] === '-2')

    console.log(result) // [['place', '1', '-2'],['place2', '1', '-2']]
```